# Relax a command inside minted

Tags: xetex, unicode, minted

I'm using rich unicode in LaTeX as specified [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238971/8992). However I also use unicode in Julia language, so when I input Julia code in XeLaTeX I get an error because √ is bound to `\sqrt` in LaTeX, but is a normal symbol in minted. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{√}{\sqrt}

\usepackage{minted} % uses minted 2.0+
% skip boxes on parser error:
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@bc##1{{\strut ##1}}}
\makeatother
% name of the code boxes:
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Код}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$√{2}$

\begin{listing}[H]
  \begin{minted}[breaklines,autogobble,linenos]{julia}
        P(a::ℝ) = k*T/A_n * (
                        (√a - 1)^(1/3) / (3 * ν^(1/3) * √a)
                      + 1 / (a - √a)
                  )
  \end{minted}
  \caption{(\ref{eq:a})\label{code:a}}
\end{listing}

$√{2}$

\end{document}
```

This should be compiled with `xelatex -shell-escape mwe.tex`. I'm looking for a way to unbind the √ inside minted environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the square root symbol `√` to behave differently in `minted`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{minted} % uses minted 2.0+

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newtoggle{inminted}
\newunicodechar{√}{\iftoggle{inminted}{√}{\sqrt}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\toggletrue{inminted}}

% skip boxes on parser error:
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@bc##1{{\strut ##1}}}
\makeatother
% name of the code boxes:
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Код}

\begin{document}

$√{2}$

\begin{listing}[H]
  \begin{minted}[breaklines,autogobble,linenos]{julia}
        P(a::ℝ) = k*T/A_n * (
                        (√a - 1)^(1/3) / (3 * ν^(1/3) * √a)
                      + 1 / (a - √a)
                  )
  \end{minted}
  \caption{(\ref{eq:a})\label{code:a}}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]